# How to connect HC-05 with c# winform application to get sensor data from arduino

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin.forms, arduino

**How to connect HC-05 with c# winform application to get sensor data from arduino**

**Requirements & steps am trying:**

1. My project is Sense temperature in arduino using mlx90614 sensor
2. Am using HC-05 Bluetooth to send data to winform by command "read"
3. Parameter has 2 values which i sending to winform "Farenheit,Celcius"
4. once data received i will send data to cload using api which i completed api part & backend part

Now i need support in sending and receiving data from winform to arduino via hc-05.
I tried but data not receiving.
Thanks in advance

Comment: *I tried but data not receiving*. For this to be a precise and clear question, you need to describe exactly what you tried.

Comment: hi luker i have explained what i am doing i want help in sending and receiving data from winform to arduino via hc-05.

Comment: Those steps are somewhat helpful, but they are still generally stated and don't indicate the details about the part you say isn't working.  You're saying you're trying to get data from the Winform to the Arduino. What Bluetooth library are you using in the WInform? How are you calling it? Did you successfully pair and connect to the HC-05 from Windows? In your Arduino code, how are you trying to receive the data? Showing some code and some details would help.